# How to set SSJS InvokePerform() configuration options?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

How to set the O2 argument in an SSJS InvokePerform() API function? O2 is referencing [this](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/accessing_api_functions_using_the_function_object/) documentation, also noted below.

> **InvokePerform(O1,S1,A1)**
> Use this function to ... [read in documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/accessing_api_functions_using_the_function_object/)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> **O1** - The object on which to perform the Perform method
> **S1** - The method
> to perform on the object
> **A1** - The array used to contain the status and
> RequestID of the API call
> **O2** - API configure options to include in the
> call (can contain a null value)
> **Example:**

```
<script runat="server">     
     var rtn = [0,0,0];
     var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokePerform(APIObject,"Validate",StatusAndRequestID,Options);
     var statusMessage = StatusAndRequestID[0];
     var errorCode = StatusAndRequestID[1];
     var performResponse = StatusAndRequestID[2];
</script>
```

Edit:
Here is the code that I have come up with using the PerformOptions() object.

```
<script runat="server">     
// Perform the query activity using ObjectID
var perform_query = Platform.Function.CreateObject("QueryDefinition");     
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(perform_query, "ObjectID", objectid);
var perform_options = Platform.Function.CreateObject("PerformOptions");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(perform_options, "RequestType", "Asynchronous")

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0,0];
var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokePerform(perform_query, "Start", StatusAndRequestID, perform_options);
var perform_statusMessage = StatusAndRequestID[0];
var perform_errorCode = StatusAndRequestID[1];
var perform_response = StatusAndRequestID[2];
    </script>
```

**Output:**
perform_statusMessage: Exception occurred during [Schedule::Start] ErrorID = 252253054

Comment: Where is the objectid variable being set?  Please check to make sure it is a valid GUID.

Comment: This is a code snippit - the objectid variable is being set prior to this code block. It is a valid GUID.

Comment: There is no issue in code, Maybe you're not passing correct ObjectID.

Comment: The error indicates that it isn't able to parse the ObjectID to a GUID, maybe a trailing space was added?

Comment: I'll check that. The goal of having an Async InvokeRequest() is to return the RequestID so that I can check the status of a QD after starting it. Once the QD is complete, I move one to the next step. Am I barking up the right tree here?